# extract value of a key in Meteor object in HTTP callback

Tags: javascript

This Meteor client code tries to get the value of the "USD" from the link "https://blockchain.info/de/ticker" but it is giving "undefined".
Any idea why and how to get the sale value of the USD? Thanks

```js
Template.currency.onRendered(function () {
  HTTP.get('https://blockchain.info/de/ticker', function (err, data) {

    console.log(data.content); // print the correct object

// {
//  "USD" : {"15m" : 16148.96, "last" : 16148.96, "buy" : 16154.48, "sell" : 16143.44, "symbol" : "$"},
//  "AUD" : {"15m" : 21164.06, "last" : 21164.06, "buy" : 21171.29, "sell" : 21156.82, "symbol" : "$"}}

    console.log(data.content["USD"]); //<<<<<<<<<< gives undefined
  });
});

Template.currency.helpers({
  bitcoinValue: function () {
    return Session.get('bitcoin');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this returned data is a String, so it returns undefined. You can do a Json parse and try that:

```
JSON.parse(data.content)["USD"]
```